# How do I incorporate the velocity of a magnet passing through a coil into Faraday's law?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Knowing that Faraday's law is $\varepsilon=-\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$, how can the velocity of a cylindrical magnet of half the radius of the loop passing **through** a coil be incorporated into the equation?

Comment: What is the geometric shape and size of the magnet? Can you add more details?